# change size of checkbox in boostrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I try to change the size of a checkbox in bootstrap. I try it like this:

css:

```
   .big-checkbox {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

HTML bootstrap:

```
  <label class="big-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="optradio">Reeks
        </label>

@section scripts{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Stickerprinter.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    }
```

But I dont see changing the size.

Comment: You have applied the css to the label, not the checkbox

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. sorry. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
  .big-checkbox  > input {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

Comment: ```div.checkbox  > input[type="checkbox"] {
   transform: scale(1.5);
}```

The above did it for me.

Comment: @OlotinTemitope , this is making the box blurry

Answer (score 6):

Using width and height you can't change the dimensions of an input checkbox. In this way change the area of click but checkbox remain the same.
You can use this:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Check the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/88v0gq20/

You can use for bootstrap this plugin: http://plugins.krajee.com/checkbox-x/demo

Or you could create custom checkbox like in this tutorial: https://kyusuf.com/post/completely-css-custom-checkbox-radio-buttons-and-select-boxes